# How can I create a new instance of a class at run time using c#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity

I have the following class which I pass Entity Framework Model when making an instance of it.

```
public class TableMapper<TSource>
{
    protected IQueryExtractor QueryExtractor { get; set; }
    protected string TableAliasPrefix { get; private set; } 

    public TableMapper(IQueryExtractor queryExtractor, string tableAliasPrefix = null)
    {
        QueryExtractor = queryExtractor;
        TableAliasPrefix = tableAliasPrefix;
    }

    public IReportRelation GetForeignRelation<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> property)
    {
        return new ReportRelation
        {
            Column = GetReportColumn(null, Self, property),
            TableName = this.Table(),
            TableAlias = this.GetSqlAlias(),
            ModelType = typeof(TSource),
            QueryExtractor = this.QueryExtractor
        };
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

I call this above class yet from another class like so

```
var clientMapper = new TableMapper<Client>(QueryExtractor, "Client");
var = clientMapper.GetForeignRelation(x => x.Id);
```

Please note that  `Client` is an Entity Framework 6 model.

From within my `GetForeignRelation` method, I set the type of `Client` or `<TSource>` so I can create a new instance of the `TableMapper` class at run time.

Here is what I tried to do in an attempt to create a new instance of it at run time.

```
var RunTimeModel = Activator.CreateInstance(relationsMapping.ModelType);
var RunTimeMapper = new TableMapper<RunTimeModel>(relationsMapping.QueryExtractor, relationsMapping.TableAlias);
```

But that is giving me an error.

> The type or namespace name `RunTimeModel` could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I correctly create a new instance of the same class at run time?

Answer (score 1):

You will get the class name of TSource with

```
typeof(TSource).Name
```

You should be able to create an instance with:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TSource));
```

as long as the type is in the same assembly
Other properties can be use to obtain the full namespace

EDIT:

Do this example apply to your scanario?
Had to strip down your provided code as I don't know what's behind it all :)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new TableMapper<A>();
        var fr = test.GetForeignRelation();
        var type = fr.ModelType;
        var newInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}

public class TableMapper<TSource>
{

    public TableMapper()
    {
    }

    public ReportRelation GetForeignRelation()
    {
        return new ReportRelation
        {
            ModelType = typeof(TSource)
        };
    }
}

public class ReportRelation
{
    public Type ModelType { get; set; }
}

public class A
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
    public A()
    {
        Test = "Some string";
    }
}
```

Comment: I store `typeof(TSource)` into a variable `relationsMapping.ForeignRelation.ModelType` like you can see in my code. then I pass that to the `Activator.CreateInstance()` but it is not working for me. Please see the error in my question

Comment: I use case is similar to what you coded. so I need to create a instance of `ReportRelation` Please keep in mind that `<TSource>` is an Entity Framework model

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass variable to a type parameter

```
var RunTimeModel = Activator.CreateInstance(relationsMapping.ModelType);
var RunTimeMapper = new TableMapper<RunTimeModel>(relationsMapping.QueryExtractor, relationsMapping.TableAlias)
```

Because RunTimeModel is not a type but a variable. I think you are missing purpose of method which you are using.

Comment: I am not sure that I know what you are telling me to change in my code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to instantiate your generic type :

```
var RunTimeMapper = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TableMapper<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { relationsMapping.ModelType }), new[] { relationsMapping.QueryExtractor, relationsMapping.TableAlias });
```

However,the return value type for RunTimeMapper is object.I cann't figure out how to cast RunTimeMapper to its actual type.So,it's a little inconvenient to use.

Referer:[How to: Examine and Instantiate Generic Types with Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6(v=vs.110).aspx)